# flv, youtube video stream on website with cross browser and iphone ipad compatibility.

Tags: jquery, ios, youtube, video-streaming

I have integrated jwplayer on my website. which is working fine in windows but not working in devices like iphone and ipad.
I want to play video from youtube or flv files from my dir. 
Can you pls suggest me player or a way to work in all browsers and devices.

Comment: The latest version of JW Player should work fine on iOS. Do you have any code examples? Try jsfiddle.net if you can't host yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (and cheapest, since you won't have to pay for bandwidth) thing would be to upload your videos to YouTube and run all video content from there, using one of the [iframe embedding methods](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters)

It might be worth noting that iOS devices (and many like it) are not able to play .flv files.  YouTube will also solve this issue by re-encoding the videos for you and automatically displaying them in a compatible way.